# Is it possible to set the IP address when launching a container?

Tags: networking, lxc, lxd

I’m looking for examples how to create/launch a container with a predefined ipv4.address? Is that even possible? I've tried with

`lxc launch image name --config 'eth0.ipv4.address=10.0.2.2'`

Though this errors out with unknown key? I'm suspecting that's a limitation of LXD?

Answer (score 2):

Not with `lxc launch image name --config` in my testing, though not ideal, the following did accomplish what I needed in the end.

Copy default profile called staticip and remove `eth0` device.

```
LXCN=lxcname
lxc init image name --profile staticip
lxc config device add $LXCN eth0 ipv4.address=10.0.3.2 nictype=bridged parent=virbr1
```